# SharePoint (VMs) in Azure using AAD Guest Account login issue

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory

SharePoint deployed on Azure VMs (not SharePoint Online), using AAD for authentication. Works fine for domain user accounts, however guest accounts (i.e. outlook.com accounts) can not authenticate (B2B/B2C) to SharePoint, receiving an HTTP Error 401.

Comment: The app has to be registered as an application for B2B/B2C. Check if you have done that

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azure B2C FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs?tabs=applications
Azure AD B2C is not meant for the SharePoint external/ partner-sharing scenario; see Azure AD B2B instead.
It appears consumer guest accounts, such as outlook.com/gmail.com, will not work, but instead rely on Azure AD B2B. Can someone confirm?